# How to upload a form result to MYSQL with NODE.JS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'd really appreciate any help with this!
In the EJS file I have partials/test which contains a multistepper form. I also have a js file added called "verificationtrade.js". In the multistepper form the user adds some data which is calculated by functions which are in the js file. These functions give the user a "result" in the last page of the form. I need to add that result to MYSQL.

I have tried different ways to do that:

- Since it is not the inputs of the form that I need to upload to MYSQL but the result of the calculations based on those inputs, I don´t think **METHOD:POST** + submit button would work (I tried it anyways but no luck).
- I tried to access the

  elements which contain the calculations results in the last page of the multistepper with document.getElementById().innerHTML and then saved it into an object or variable and upload that object to MYSQL, but no luck. When I try to import the database connection into the verification.js file I get an error saying "Cannot use import outside a module".
  If I change the verification.js file to **type=module** instead of text/javascript the functions I have on that file stop working. So I can´t change the type of the script. (I already have type=module in PackageJson FYI)
- I also tried to do *inline script* in the EJS file to add the calculations functions there and change the type of the JS script to module so I could import the database connection but after I did that I get a 404 code ERROR saying it cannot find the database file where the connection is. So then as a workaround I tried to write the whole connection code in order not to import the database connection from another file, starting with **import mysql from 'mysql'** but then after doing that I get this other ERROR saying "Failed to resolve module specifier "mysql". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I don´t know what else to do... If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it! **How can I upload this form result to MYSQL?**

index.js

```js
import express from "express";
import {dirname, join} from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from "url"
import rutas from './routes/index.js'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import session from "express-session";
import MySQLStore from "express-mysql-session";

import path from 'path';
import passport from "passport";
import flash from "connect-flash";
import localStrategy from "./lib/passport.js";

const app = express()
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', join(__dirname, 'views')) 
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public'))) 

//MIDDLEWARES
app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'alissarobot', 
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false, 
    store: new MySQLStore({host: 'localhost',
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'alissa',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'AEHLAEHL19961996'}) })); 
app.use(flash());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()) 
app.use(passport.initialize()); 
app.use(passport.session());

//GLOBAL VARIABLES
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    app.locals.message = req.flash('message');
    app.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    app.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
})

//ROUTES
app.use(rutas)
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.listen(8000)
console.log('Server is listening on port', 8000);
```

alissa.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ALISSA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/profile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/alissa.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    <%- include('partials/head') %>

</head>
<body style="background-color: #f5f6f5" ;>

    <%- include('partials/navigation') %>
        <%- include('partials/test') %>
            <div>
                <div class="wave"></div>
                <div class="wave"></div>
                <div class="wave"></div>
            </div>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./verificationtrade.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

database.js

```
import mysql from 'mysql';
import { createPool } from 'mysql';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'alissa',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'AEHLAEHL19961996'
});
   
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {  console.log(err)  }

    if (connection) connection.release();
    console.log('DB IS CONNECTED');
    return;
});

pool.query = promisify(pool.query); //para convertir callbacks en promesas
export default pool;
```

test.ejs

```
 <div class="container">
    <form id="msform" action="/alissa" method="POST">
        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active">Hora</li>
            <li>Ciclo</li>
            <li>Precio</li>
            <li>Peaks</li>
            <li>Ciclo</li>
            <li>Precio</li>
            <li>Peaks</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
            
            <h3 class="mt-3 mb-4" style="color: white; font-family: Raleway;">Nueva operación</h3>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle mt-1 mb-3" style="color: white; font-size: 14px; ">Selecciona la divisa</h3>

            <select id="list" onchange="getSelectedValue(); "
                class="btn btn-light iniciar dropdown-toggle mb-4 mt-3 pl-3 pr-3" type="button "
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 5px;" name="parpar">
                <option value="Divisa">Divisa</option>
                <option value="EurUsd">EurUsd</option>
                <option value="GbpUsd">GbpUsd</option>
                <option value="UsdChf">UsdChf</option>       
            </select>
            <br>          
            <input type="button" name="next" class="btn btn-primary next action-button mt-4" value="Continuar"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>

            <h3 class="mt-3 mb-4" style="color: white; font-family: Raleway;">Tiempo</h3>

            <h3 class="fs-subtitle mt-1 mb-3" style="color: white; font-size: 14px;">Ingresa la hora actual</h3>
                <select id="datehour" onchange="getSelectedHour(); "
                class="btn btn-light iniciar dropdown-toggle mb-4 pl-3 pr-3 text-center" type="button number"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 5px; padding-bottom: 7px;" >
                <option style="text-align: center" value="">Hora</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="1">1</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="2">2</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="3">3</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="4">4</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="5">5</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="6">6</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="7">7</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="8">8</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="9">9</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="10">10</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="11">11</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="12">12</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="13">13</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="14">14</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="15">15</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="16">16</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="17">17</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="18">18</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="19">19</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="20">20</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="21">21</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="22">22</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="23">23</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="24">24</option>
            </select>
            <select id="dateminutes" onchange="getSelectedMinutes(); "
                class="btn btn-light iniciar dropdown-toggle mb-4 pl-3 pr-3 text-center" type="button number"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 5px; padding-bottom: 7px;" >
                <option style="text-align: center" value="">Minutos</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="00">00</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="05">05</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="10">10</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="15">15</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="20">20</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="25">25</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="30">30</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="35">35</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="40">40</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="45">45</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="50">50</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="55">55</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle mt-1 mb-3" style="color: white; font-size: 14px;">¿Qué día es hoy?</h3>
            <select id="day" onchange="getSelectedDay();"
                class="btn btn-light iniciar dropdown-toggle mb-4 pl-3 pr-3 text-center" type="button "
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 5px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
                <option style="text-align: center" value="">Día</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="Lunes">Lunes</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="Martes">Martes</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="Miercoles">Miercoles</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="Jueves">Jueves</option>
                <option style="text-align: center" value="Viernes">Viernes</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="btn btn-primary previous action-button mt-4" value="Previous"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="btn btn-primary next action-button mt-4" value="Continuar"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h3 class="mt-3 mb-4" style="color: white; font-family: Raleway;">Precio actual</h3>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle mt-1 mb-3" style="color: white; font-family: Raleway; font-size: 14px;">Ingresa el punto en el que se
                encuentra el
                mercado en tu divisa en este momento</h3>
            <input onchange="getSelectedPrice();" id="price" type="number"  placeholder="Precio actual" class="mb-4"/> 
           
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="btn btn-primary previous action-button mt-4" value="Previous"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="btn btn-primary next action-button mt-4" value="Continuar"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h3 class="mt-3 mb-4" style="color: white; font-family: Raleway;">6pm - 12:30am</h3>

            <h3 class="fs-subtitle mt-1 mb-3" style="color: white; font-family: Raleway; font-size: larger; font-size: 14px;">Ingresa el punto máximo (más
                alto) y el punto
                mínimo (más bajo) al que llegó el mercado en tu divisa durante esas horas</h3>
            <input onchange="getAsiaMaxPrice();" id="asiamaxprice" type="int" name="fname"
                placeholder="Precio máximo" />
            <input onchange="getAsiaMinPrice();" id="asiaminprice" type="int" name="lname"
                placeholder="Precio mínimo" class="mb-4"/>

            <input type="button" name="previous" class="btn btn-primary previous action-button mt-4" value="Previous"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
            <input  type="button" id="" onclick="newTrade2();newTrade3(); newOperation();  newTrade4(); newTrade5(); newTrade6(); newTrade7(); newTrade8(); tradingzonesell(); notradingzoneyet(); asiarange(); greattrade(); notradingzoneyetforbuy(); badhourtrading(); goodtradebuy(); greattradebuy(); newTrade9(); below1hour(); " 
            
                class="btn next action-button btn-primary mt-4" value="Enviar"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h5 style="color: white" class=" text-center">Ayer</h5>
            <p style="font-family: Raleway; color: white;">Ingresa el punto máximo (más alto) y el punto
                mínimo (más bajo) al que llegó el mercado en tu divisa ayer
            </p>
            <input  onchange="getMaxAyer()" id="maximoayer" type="int" name="fname" placeholder="Precio máximo" autofocus style="color: black; font-family: Raleway; font-size: larger; font-size: 14px;"/>
            <input onchange="getMinAyer()" id="minimoayer"  type="int" name="lname" placeholder="Precio mínimo" style="color: black; font-family: Raleway; font-size: larger; font-size: 14px;"/>
  
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="btn btn-primary previous action-button mt-4" value="Previous"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="btn btn-primary next action-button mt-4" value="Continuar"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h5 style="color: white" class=" text-center">Anteayer</h5>
            <p style="font-family: Raleway; color: white;">Ingresa el punto máximo (más alto) y el punto
                mínimo (más bajo) al que llegó el mercado en tu divisa anteayer
            </p>
            <input id="maximoanteayer" onchange="getMaxAnteayer()"  type="int" name="fname" placeholder="Precio máximo" autofocus style="color: black; font-family: Raleway; font-size: larger; font-size: 14px;"/>
            <input id="minimoanteayer"  onchange="getMinAnteayer()" type="int" name="lname" placeholder="Precio mínimo" style="color: black; font-family: Raleway; font-size: larger; font-size: 14px;"/>
        
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="btn btn-primary previous action-button mt-4" value="Previous"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="btn btn-primary next action-button mt-4" value="Continuar"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
              
            <h5 style="color: white" class=" text-center">Hace 3 días</h5>
            <p style="font-family: Raleway; color: white;">Ingresa el punto máximo (más alto) y el punto
                mínimo (más bajo) al que llegó el mercado en tu divisa hace 3 días
            </p>
            <input onchange="getMaxTdias()" id="maximo3dias" type="int" name="fname" placeholder="Precio máximo" autofocus style="color: black; font-family: Raleway; font-size: larger; font-size: 14px;"/>
            <input onchange="getMinTdias()" id="minimo3dias" type="int" name="fname" placeholder="Precio mínimo" style="color: black; font-family: Raleway; font-size: larger; font-size: 14px;"/>
        
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="btn btn-primary previous action-button mt-4" value="Previous"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />
            <input  type="button" id="" onclick="uptrend(); downtrend(); stophuntsell(); stophuntbuy(); consolidacion();  alcista(); bajista(); posiblestophuntbajista();  posiblestophuntalcista(); tiempoconsolidacion(); status(); status1(); status2(); status3();  " 
            
                class="btn next action-button btn-primary mt-4" value="Enviar"
                style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" />

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <img style="border-radius: 50px" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/blonde-icon-flat-style-white-background-woman-symbol-stock-vector-illustration-79131143.jpg" height="50" width="50" />           
            <h5 style="color: white" class=" text-center mt-2">¡Hora de hacer  trading!</h5>
            <p style="font-family: Raleway; color: white; background-color: green; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 20px;" class="mt-4 pl-3 pr-3" id="tradeorientation" name="tipo"  >Compra</p>
            <br>
            <p style="font-family: Raleway; color: white;">Calidad del trade: <span
                style="font-weight: bold; color: white;" id="calidadtrade" name="ctrade">Buena</span> </p>
             <p style="font-family: Raleway; color: white;">Take Profit:<span style="font-weight: bold" id="takeprofit" name="tomaganancia">1.256</span></p>
             <p style="font-family: Raleway; color: white;" class="mb-1">Stop Loss: <span style="font-weight: bold" id="stoploss" name="tomaperdida">1.153</span></p>
             <br>
             <p class="mt-4" style="font-family: Raleway; color: white;" id="comment">Si la operación no está en ganancia en 3 horas ciérrala</p>
            <a href="/profile"><input type=" button" onclick="build();" class="btn btn-primary mt-4" value="Listo" style="color: white; font-weight: bolder;" /></a>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about which JavaScript program can do what.

You have three programs (all written in JS, but all distinct).

1. Your HTTP server (using Express and Node.js). This is responsible for listening for HTTP requests and sending responses to the browser. It is also responsible for anything you want to do with the data the browser sends you.
2. Your EJS program. This is run on the server, but should be considered separate. It is the JS between tags like `<%` and `%>`. It is responsible for taking data passed to it by **1** and turning it into HTML (at which point it passed the HTML document back to **1** to send to the browser).
3. Your `<script>` elements. These run on the browser and are responsible for any processing of the data you want to do that, and for updating the DOM in the browser without going back to the server.

---

Any interaction with the database should be done by **1** (the HTTP server). It doesn't make sense to do it with **2** (the template) and *can't* be done with **3** (client-side code).

If you are running calculations on the client (using **3**) and want to put the results in your database then your options are:

- Submit the data the user entered to the server using a form. Redo the calculations on the server.
- Submit the data the client-side JS generated using a form. This will involve generating or updating `input` elements (e.g. `<input type="hidden" ...>`) using client-side JavaScript and then submitting the form.
- Submit the data the client-side JS generated using Ajax (typically using [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). This lets you send that data without leaving the page the user is currently looking at.

Comment: I will go ahead and try that.  Thanks!